# Google Forms Multiple Languages

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-research, user-expectation, surveys

At work, it's very common to have a google form on our website.

Someone recently asked me if it's a good idea to have a separate form for each language, or if it's ok to have it all in one form.

I've googled it, but not really getting anything (apparently google-fu is awful) ...

Languages are English, Japanese, and Korean.

What's the best answer to give here? It's ok to put all the questions in multiple languages in one form, or it's best to have separate forms for each language?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently conducted surveys via Google forms in our startup, and decided to separate languages (English and French) in two distinct forms.

It is easier to read statistics of for each language community, which make sense in some cases (obviously did for us at least).

Thus, I would recommend to do separate forms.